# Which Mongo instance in Replica Set did the application call?

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a Java application, which works with a Mongo *replica set*. The replica set consists of two Mongo instances (primary and secondary) in different hosts

Suppose the application is executing a query (e.g. find a document in a collection). I don't know what [read preference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/) it uses. Suppose also that both *primary* and *secondary* instances store the same data.

Now I need to know *which* Mongo instance the application has called to execute the query: the *primary*, the *secondary*, or the both.

How can I do that ?

I would prefer a solution, which does not require access to the application code.

Comment: How do you know what queries the application is running? How do you know what to look for? You could check the log but then what hpapens if two apps are accessing differnt read prefernces?

Comment: You can increase verboseness of mongod logs. At a certain level, it'll start dumping all queries to the log. This is a starting point.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks. I am afraid changing the log level requires Mongo restart. What if I will use profiling instead ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default read preference is primary so if you didn't change it, that's where it's reading.

Comment: Thanks. Suppose I do not know _exactly_ what read preference is used. Suppose also I don't have access to the sources. How can I find _which_ Mongo instance in the replica set is called ?

Comment: You'd have to trawl the logs as mentioned above.  What exactly are you trying to find?  There are probably better ways of doing this.

Comment: In a nutshell, I have an application, which works against a Mongo replica set. _Looks like_ the app. uses _nearest_ read pref. to query. However it _looks like_ it calls _primary_ instead of _secondary_ although the _primary_ is in another data center and the _secondary_ is  in the same data center. That's the whole story ...

Comment: Yeah, you'll probably just have to tail the logs to verify.  You can get at that kind of information from the driver but it requires a bit of surgery in your code.

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain how to get this info from the driver. I have access to the code actually ...

Comment: Meanwhile I am trying to use profiling (`setProfilingLevel(2)`) in both instances instead of logging.

Comment: You can use [getServerAddress()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.4/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#getServerAddress()) to find which server processed a given query.  You might get odd results in a sharded cluster as multiple servers might be involved, though.

Comment: Great ! I will try it. The cluster I am working with is not sharded, so it should not be a problem.