# How to get Mongo server address when I call findOne API

Tags: java, mongodb

This is a follow-up of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554271/which-mongo-instance-in-replica-set-did-the-application-call). Suppose I have an application, which uses `nearest` read preference. Now I would like to verify which `Mongo` node *actually* handles queries.

I know I can get the address of that `Mongo` node with `DBCursor.getServerAddress` API.

Suppose I call `DBCollection.findOne`, which returns a single `DBObject` rather than `DBCursor`. How can I get the `Mongo` node address in this case ?

Comment: The real question is why? Shouldn't it be part of the point of architecture that your application should not care? I think you should care to explain yourself in your question if you expect a meaningful response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is you don't. The [findOne](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOne/) implementation is just a convenience wrapper around an ordinary [find](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/), that simply limits the response to one document as opposed to returning a cursor.

As such, the [BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) returned is really just a simple wrapper around [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) (*With ordered keys and a certain view of serializing*) ultimately and thus does not have the special properties associated with a [DBCursor](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.0/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html) object.

Therefore if it **really** is important to you then what you **actually** want to do is use a regular `find` and **limit** the results to **one**. Here you manually handle what `findOne` is doing and you have access to the cursor in order to call [getServerAddress()](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.4/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#getServerAddress%28%29) as required.

That said, I would **strongly** discourage you from doing this unless you had a real reason (e.g. analysis tool) for doing so. The reason being, as you were given in the [response to your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21556077/2313887), is that the read really **should** be coming from the primary. And even if you *accept* reading from a secondary, your application should not care.

However, go and use as you wish.